# Required Node FS module found but can't call functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, fs

I am hoping this is something simple that I'm just oblivious to, but I've been looking around for a solution to no avail.

When I set a variable to "require('fs')," I can see that it is being defined as an object in the scope, but when I try to call something like fs.readFile, I get a function not found exception in the browser.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile("geo.csv","utf8",function(err,raw){
  //things
});
```

Is is possible that I'm not assigning the correct object somehow or am I possibly calling the function incorrectly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(Node version is 8.0)

Comment: in the browser? the `fs` module is one of those node.js module you can't use in the browser even if you are using `browserify` or anyother bundler, except if you are using electron

Comment: Okay, then I clearly haven't understood how to use this properly. Sorry for my ignorance. I will attempt to look more at the documentation on how to actually run the module and generate the file I'm looking to create.

Comment: why don't you use the `FileReader` html5 api. I don't know it's presents state, you can search for that on google yourself , right ?

Comment: Yeah, I can look into it more. The issue originally stemmed from trying to leverage a node module for creating geocoded data from csv files using the GoogleMaps API. Now that I understand its correct usage, I should be able to approach the issue with the correct mindset and get it working as intended. Thank you for your help!